# JS instruction - Hex code

Tags: gcc, assembly, hex, 64-bit

I tried to cover asm to hex by gcc ( gcc -c -masm=intel code.s) by it error: code.s:1: Error: too many memory references for `mov'.
code.s asm:

```
mov rax , 0x00000000004007E6
js rax
```

what happened? Can you tutorial me cover it?

Comment: Are you using Intel syntax? NASM may be more suitable for this task as it supports Intel syntax and can produce raw binaries. *-masm=intel* is an output option AFAIK.

Comment: `js rax` looks like you use `rax` as a label, but it is of course also a register. If it *is* used as a label, you would have two memory references for the `mov`.

Comment: yes i use intel code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Margaret Bloom said, `-masm=intel` is only a code generation option, meaning it affects what kind of assembly the compiler generates from C code. It does not affect assembling at all.

You need to put `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive in your assembly file to switch syntax, or use the convoluted `gcc -Wa,--msyntax=intel,-mnaked-reg` method to pass argument to the assembler.

Having done the above, the next issue will be that `js rax` is invalid as there is no conditional indirect jump in x86. The easiest will be probably to use a reversed condition, `jns`, to skip over a `jmp rax`.